# Apache storm 9.2 missing in storm-starter

Tags: apache-storm

I download storm-starter from github:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter

There is a missing dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.2-incubating-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <!-- keep storm out of the jar-with-dependencies -->
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

With 0.9.1-incubating meven resolve the dependency.
Can I use it in the storm-starter example?
There are incompatibilities?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved the problem.

First of all you have tu use version 0.9.1-incubating (with "0.9.2-incubating-SNAPSHOT" maven can not solve the dependency).

Secondly, using eclipse, it add the org.eclipse.m2e plugin.
notice the comment:

```
<!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
```

This is not so true
It seems that the tag

```
<versionRange>[1.3.18,)</versionRange>
```

causes the download of the version 1.3.18
of the plugin "clojure-maven-plugin".
This causes a ClassNotFound exception for  for org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$Factory.

To solve the problem you can force the version 1.3.8 of the clojure-maven-plugin.
Or set the version range of the org.eclipse.m2e plugin to [1.3.8,).

Here my working pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
      <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
      <version>0.9.1-incubating</version>
      <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>storm-starter</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>storm-starter</name>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
      <artifactId>fest-assert-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.0M8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
      <artifactId>jmock</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <!-- keep storm out of the jar-with-dependencies -->
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/jvm</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test/jvm</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/multilang</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
      <!--
        Bind the maven-assembly-plugin to the package phase
        this will create a jar file without the storm dependencies
        suitable for deployment to a cluster.
       -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass></mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.theoryinpractise</groupId>
        <artifactId>clojure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <sourceDirectories>
            <sourceDirectory>src/clj</sourceDirectory>
          </sourceDirectories>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>java</executable>
          <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
          <includePluginDependencies>false</includePluginDependencies>
          <classpathScope>compile</classpathScope>
          <mainClass>${storm.topology}</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        com.theoryinpractise
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        clojure-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.3.8,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

try following dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>storm</groupId>
<artifactId>storm</artifactId>
<version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Amit.
Sorry but why 0.8.2 and not 0.9.1-incubating?

Comment: sorry @AndreaZonzin i copy the dependency and paste it,i edit the answer hopefully its work for you.

Comment: With 0.9.1 maven resolves the dependency. But when I compile with maven it causes
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$Factory

Comment: With "0.9.1" version, still maven can not resolve the dependency. 
With "0.9.1-incubating" the pom is ok but with your suggest "mvn -f m2-pom.xml package" I still have the problem of ClassNotFoundException for org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn$Factory